# sql UPDATE inside Stored Procedure appears to work - but it is not recorded in the data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

The following procedure is executed with these values: `(0, 1, 'CNI', 'CNI')`

The `CNI/CNI` record has a value of 10,000 in `SpecialFeatureCreditBalance`

The procedure returns (correctly) 9,999

Checking the `CNI/CNI` record shows a value of 10,000 (should be 9,999)

Running the procedure multiple times always returns the same value (9,999)

Changing the value of `@Value` does show the correct result, but again the new balance is not reflected in the database (`@Value` of 2 always returns 9,998 for example)

I've tried wrapping all or part of the procedure in `BEGIN TRANS/COMMIT` but that only causes run time errors.

I'm stuck.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UseSFC] @DealerPays TinyInt, @Value Int, @DealerID Char(3), @CustomerID Char(3)
```

BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
   IF @DealerPays = 1 OR (SELECT [DealerPays] 
                          FROM dbo.Customer 
                          WHERE [DealerID] = @DealerID AND [ID] = @CustomerID) = 1
      IF (SELECT [SpecialFeatureCreditBalance] 
          FROM dbo.Dealer 
          WHERE [ID] = @DealerID) >= @Value
      BEGIN
         UPDATE dbo.Dealer 
         SET [SpecialFeatureCreditBalance] = [SpecialFeatureCreditBalance] - @Value 
         WHERE [ID] = @DealerID;

         RETURN 1
      END
      ELSE
         RETURN 0
   ELSE
      IF (SELECT [SpecialFeatureCreditBalance] 
          FROM dbo.Customer 
          WHERE [DealerID] = @DealerID AND [ID] = @CustomerID) >= @Value
      BEGIN
         UPDATE dbo.Customer 
         SET [SpecialFeatureCreditBalance] = [SpecialFeatureCreditBalance] - @Value 
         WHERE [DealerID] = @DealerID AND [ID] = @CustomerID;

         RETURN (SELECT [SpecialFeatureCreditBalance]  
                 FROM dbo.Customer 
                 WHERE [DealerID] = @DealerID AND [ID] = @CustomerID)
      END 
      ELSE  
          RETURN 0
   END
```

Comment: Could you add the complete procedure definition/header so one can see what variables `(0, 1, 'CNI', 'CNI')` actually map to? I'm having a bit of trouble following your description of the behavior without it.

Comment: it's interesting: what runtime errors were caused by `begin tran` / `commit`? Seems like you have an outer transaction and it gets rolled back.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Not sure why it looks like two code blocks, but I added the line with the parameter definitions

Comment: @dean - Yeah, that's what I thought, and why I tried adding BEGIN TRANS and COMMIT.  But then I get an error message about an error with BEGIN/COMMIT.  It complains that the number of BEGIN/COMMIT has been changed - previously 1, now 2.  The error message is puzzling, implying that the code you see has one, which of course it doesn't.  But the UPDATE is definitely performed, because the RETURN gives the expected answer, but then must be rolled back as the new value is not reflected in the database itself or on a subsequent operation.